# Xamarin forms to MAUI migration issues

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have tried to migrate my `Xamarin Forms` app to `MAUI` using `.NET 7` using the upgrade assistant extension in visual studio. First I migrated the solution, then android and finally the iOS projects. **(Is this workflow correct?)**

After that I have deleted the `bin and obj` folders, clean the project and done Rebuild.

But I am getting below errors when rebuilding the project.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net7.0-android   MyProject.Android   E:\My Projects\Xamarin.Net7\MyProject-app\MyProject\MyProject.Android\MyProject.Android.csproj 1

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier android was not recognized.  MyProject   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   113

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.  MyProject   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   113

I found a similar thread [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5778) for the first issue and found a similar thread [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8072) for the 2nd and 3rd issues. But I didn't get a clear picture of what fix need to do?

**I also tried the migration with `.NET 8` and getting same above errors. My project is already available on stores. So if we create a new MAUI project and move all the files into it, is it approve by the stores?**

Comment: Did you try to [Manually upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/forms-projects)?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I have started the migration manually, but I have one doubt. My project is already available on play and app stores. So if I create a new MAUI project and add all my stuff from xamarin forms project to new MAUI project, and if upload a new apk or ipa file with same keystore and provisioning profile, is the upload will success? or they reject it due to it is a new project?